# Scheduling a program with cron with a very specific range

Tags: linux, cron

I need to run a script every 15 minutes starting at 9:30 AM until 4:00 PM Monday through Friday only. I want to use cron on my linux system.

My attempt looks something like this:

```
/15, 30 9-16 * * 1-5
```

My question is if cron will recognize the starting point as 9:30 or if there's another way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

So here is a thought...I haven't tested it, but I plugged it into https://crontab.guru.

Could you try 2 separate entries in your crontab?
One that is the following:

```
30/15 9-16 * * 1-5 <your command>
```

And then a second one:

```
0-29/15 10-16 * * 1-5 <your command>
```

The first one starts at 9:30 and then runs for the 15 minute intervals between the second half hour (9:30, 9:45, 10:30, 10:45, etc.).  The second one starts at 10:00 and only runs for the 15 minute intervals below 30 (10:00, 10:15, 11:00, 11:15, etc.). According to the output from crontab.guru, it looks like it might work.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use from 9AM to  4PM , as I'm not sure implementing 9.30 till end at 4 in single line

00,15,30,45 09-16 * * 1-5 command*****

If you want exactly start at 9.30, you would end up adding two lines.

30,45 09-15 * * 1-5 command
00,15 10-16 * * 1-5 command